# Why isn't this loop working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-imaging-library, pixel

So basically I am trying to rearrange certain pixels within an image. The pixels to be rearranged are stored in two lists called xpixels and ypixels, where a pair from both corresponds to the pixel coordinate to be rearranged in the original image. However, my function is only rearranging the pixels on the y axis, and only for the first column. I'm not really sure why this is happening, can only think that the outer loop is not being processed correctly for some reason, or just faulty logic on my part. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    for i in range(x1, x2): #range of x coordinates in original image

        for j in range(y1, y2): #range of y coordinates in original image
            if ycounter >= len(ypixels):
                break
            else:
        #pixmap is a pixelaccess object containing image data    
                pixmap[i, j]=pixmap[i, ypixels[ycounter]] #this shuffles the first y column
                ycounter=ycounter+1
```

Comment: Did you mean for the lines after `else` to be tabbed to the right twice? If not, you should.

Comment: yes, i just fixed it(thanks for the heads up)

Comment: what values does ycounter get? by ycounter, did you actually mean j?

Comment: ycounter is a global counter i have outside of this loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what this code is doing, but I guess you need to reset the value of `ycounter` at the start of each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: oh wow, that actually did it, thank you! I was actually resetting the ycounter outside the for loop, and that appears to be what tripped the program up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to figure out what your problem consist of, but i tried to visualize it:

```
pixmap = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        pixmap[i][j] = '1'


for i in range(5):
    pixmap[j][i] = '0'

print "Original Matrix:"
for i in range(5):
    print pixmap[i]

def rearrange_funct(oldPos,newPos):
    original_posX, original_posY = oldPos
    rearrange_posX, rearrange_posY = newPos
    oldContent = pixmap[original_posX][original_posY]
    pixmap[original_posX][original_posY] = pixmap[rearrange_posX][rearrange_posY]
    pixmap[rearrange_posX][rearrange_posY] = oldContent



oldPixelPositions = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)]

newPixelPositions = [(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)]
for x in range(len(oldPixelPositions)):
    rearrange_funct(oldPixelPositions[x],newPixelPositions[x])

print "Rearranged Matrix:"
for i in range(5):
    print pixmap[i]
```

Is that what you're trying to achieve ?